# Is Angular 2 replacing plain old AngularJS or is it an alternative?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Since Angular 2 now uses components and the previous version is based on MVC, I would guess that migrating from one to the other requires some extensive refactoring, unless I am missing anything?

In this case, isn't Angular 2 more of an alternative?

Otherwise, I do not see why a functional AngularJS project would require migrating to Angular2 at all if refactoring is involved, unless there is a payback in updating?

Comment: I'm don't really follow angularjs, but are new features still being added or is it only in maintenance mode? That would be one question to ask.

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/should-you-learn-angular-1-or-angular-2 This would help you understanding.

Comment: I will say its more of an alternative. There is a large difference between the two. You can reuse almost none of your knowledge (or very minimal) from the older framework. Migrating an app is almost a re-work. Obviously paybacks are there in terms of performance, reuse-ability of components, modularity.

Answer (score 3):

## Pros :

There are quite a lot of benefits :

1. TypeScipt - With TypeScript you can use ECMAScript6 which comes with
   lots of new exciting features :

   Class and Module Support

   - Static Type-checking
   - ES6 Feature Support
   - Clear Library API Definition
   - Build-in Support for JavaScript Packaging
   - Syntax Similarity to Our Backend Languages (Java, Scala)
   - Superset of JavaScript

   2) Dependency Injection

## Cons :

1. Concepts like $scope, watch and directive are removed.
2. The documentation for Javascript purists on Angular 2 are lacking.
    AngularJS 1 developers still have to go through a learning curve.
3. In the Typescript and Dart, it is definitely not an ‘at-home’ feeling for many die-hard Javascript developers.

Comment: There is a good blog at : https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/angular-2-upgrading-from-1-5 to upgrade to angular 2

Comment: I use AngularJS 1.6 and have gulp with babel, so I have support for es6 and up.